# How to put conditions in chained filter for ALL or Something in Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting a `some_id` from request. If the `some_id` is `-1` I have to select ALL or select the particular `some_id`.

So I want something like this -

`model.objects.filter(some_id = '*' if some_id_val = -1 else some_id_val, some_id_2 = '*' if some_id_val_2 = -1 else some_id_val_2, ... )`

I know I can chain with `if` like -

```
qs = model.objects.all()
if some_id_val != -1:
    qs = qs.filter(some_id = some_id_val)
if some_id_val_2 != -1:
    qs = qs.filter(some_id_2 = some_id_val_2)
.
.
.
```

But I want a one liner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it empty:

```py
model.objects.filter(**{} if some_id_val = -1 else id=some_id_val)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this was not asked in question. But I have multiple key=val in `filter`. By doing this i can only use single filter condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a series of Q() objects into a list, then use and_ or or_ from the operator library to chain them together and create your ORM filter.

```
from operator import and_, or_
from django.db.models import Q

filters = []
# build the filters as Q() objects
if condition:
    filters.append(Q(attribute=value))
else:
    filters.append(Q(attribute=other_value))
# repeat as needed.

# then chain them as needed with or_ OR and_ like: 
Model.objects.filter(reduce(or_, filters))
```

Comment: Its a glorified solution to my already known technique TBH. I don't want to go in to that `if` ladder.